# Finding a particular path in weighted tree

Tags: algorithms

> I have undirected weighted linear tree (path tree) with $n$ nodes ,and
> a weight function on edges $\omega: \mathbb{N}\to  \mathbb{N}$,
> additionally given $k\in \mathbb{N}$, How we can find a path with
> lenght $k$ that have minimum number of edges in $O(n)$?[image]

I think as follow:
Run Bellman Ford for each node and then select a path with length $k$ and minimum number of edges. Unfortunately runtime $\omega(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find, for each vertex $i$, the first vertex $j_i > i$ such that the distance $d(i, j_i)$ between $i$ and $j_i$ is at least $k$.
Then, you can return the pair $(i, j_i)$ such that $d(i,j_i)=k$ and $j_i-i$ is minimized.

This takes $O(n)$ time once you notice that, for $i_1 < i_2$, $j_{i_1} \le j_{i_2}$.
In pseudocode, where $w(\ell, \ell+1)$ denotes the weight of edge $(\ell, \ell+1)$:

```
i = j = 1
best_i = 0
best_j = n
d = 0

while i != n:
  if d<k and j!=n:
    d = d + w(j, j+1)
    j=j+1
  else:
    d = d - w(i, i+1)
    i=i+1

  if d == k and j - i < best_j - best_i:
    best_i=i
    best_j=j

return best_i, best_j
```

Comment: $j_i-i$ must maximized? i think must minimized.

Comment: @myarge. My bad. I fixed it. It doesn't make much of a difference anyway.

Comment: Hello, could you explain you idea in simple manner? Thank you.

Comment: Scan the vertices of the path from left to right. For each vertex $i$, find the right endpoint as the leftmost vertex $j$ that is "to the right" of $i$ has is at a distance of at least $k$.  The solution can be found by examining only these pairs $(i,j)$.
To get a running time of $O(n)$ you can notice that the position of the vertices $j$ must either stay the same or move right, when $i$ changes.

Comment: Thank you. If the our tree has at most degree 3 for each vertex, can we solve the problem in $O(n^2\log n)$?

Comment: In $O(n^2 \log n)$ what? If it's time, then you can obviously do that. In fact you can do that in time $O(n^2)$ regardless of the degree.

Comment: Suppose each node in our tree has degree at most 3, how we can solve above problem in $O(n\log^2 n)$? We try find a path with length $k$ with minimal number of edges.